# IQueryable.QueryProvider.CreateQuery Exception: "Argument expression is not valid"

Tags: c#, linq

The code below is in a Generic class of T that inherits from List - hence why I don't know anything about the object and why I'm passing in a column name to the method.

The Exception comes in almost the last line of the method.

```
 public decimal? Max (string column) 
    {
        IQueryable<T> queryableData = this.AsQueryable<T>();

        // Compose the expression tree that represents the parameter to the predicate.
        ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");

        // ***** Select(item => item.[column]) *****
        // Create an expression tree that represents the expression 'item.[column] == "id"'
        Expression left = null;
        try
        {
            left = Expression.Property(pe, typeof(T).GetProperty(column, System.Type.EmptyTypes));
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        // Create an expression tree that represents the expression
        // 'queryableData.Select(item => item.[column]) '
        MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = null;
        try
        {
            whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable),
                "Select",
                new Type[] { queryableData.ElementType, typeof(int) },
                queryableData.Expression,
                Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>(left, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));

        }
        catch
        {
        }
        IQueryable<T> results = null;

            string lexpression = whereCallExpression.ToString();
            // Create an executable query from the expression tree.

            //Exception at this line of Code:
             results= queryableData.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(whereCallExpression);

        return Convert.ToInt32(results.Max());
    }
```

The Expression that is passed in (i.e whereCallEWxpression) appears to be correct, but this exception keeps coming up: "Argument expression is not valid". I'm really stuck and have not been able to find a solution.

Also, if anyone knows of a better way of achieving this, please do let me know - its all I could think of.

Thanks,

Roberto

**Edit:** the contruction to whereCallExpression is probably wrong. The issue then, is how to fix it. Thats really the difficult bit that i can't understand.

**Edit 2:** try catch block removed - was only in there for debugging purposes.

Comment: Your `try`..`catch` use seems silly: you don't actually prevent any exceptions (you'll get an exception on the `return` statement if anything failed earlier, because `results` will be `null`), you just prevent the exception from containing any useful information.

Comment: hvd - Its not the return. The call to CreateQuery throws the exception. Obviously, then, the construction of whereCallExpression is wrong. Its just not clear to me how its wrong.

Comment: @RobertoBonini it's somewhat OT, but his point still stands unless you omitted your catch block contents for the sake of brevity.

Comment: Ah - I see his point now. It was only in there for debugging. Removed it to make it clearer. Apologies to hvd

Answer (score 2):

To answer your "better way of achieving this", and assuming that you know what T is at the time that you are calculating Max, why would you not just use the built in `IEnumerable.Max()` extension method?  Assuming your class inherits from `List<T>` as you seem to say the the beginning of your question, this should work:

```
var myClass = new YourClass<Person>(); // obviously this would have been initialized and filled elsewhere
var maxAge = myClass.Max(p => p.Age); //Assuming Person has an Age property
```

If you truly need this inside of your class, you can do something like this in your class (untested code ahead):

```
public class myClass<T> : List<T> {
    private readonly Func<T, decimal> _fieldGetter;

    public myClass(Func<T, decimal> fieldGetter) {
         _fieldGetter = fieldGetter;
    }

    // then your Max becomes:
    public decimal? Max() {
        return this.Max(i => _fieldGetter(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: I would do it that way - But I have no idea what T or its properties are, so I don't see how I could write a lambda to target a specific property when i don't until run-time what T and the property are.

Comment: Ah, are you doing `typeof(myClass<>).MakeGenericType( ... )` or something?  Normally, I'd expect the code that I posted to be called by the consumer of your class, and I'd expect the consumer to know how to resolve the field.

Comment: Something like that. There's an attribute on the property of T. And thats how the code knows which field to use to calculate Max on. So to use your approach, the attribute class could have the Func<T, decimal> _fieldGetter and I just pass that into your Modified Max method??

Comment: No, I didn't realize an attribute was involved.  You could use reflection to iterate the properties, looking for the one that has the attribute, but that's not a great architecture.  What if multiple properties have the attribute?  It's vastly preferable to use static resolution for properties here.

Comment: Which is precisely why I went for Dynamic LINQ. I've got it working before, but not for Select. I can't find documentation on Select either. But I'll try your suggestion and see.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!

The answer was right in front of me... thanks to Chris Shain for putting me on the right track

```
var result =this.Select(c => c.GetType().GetProperty(column).GetValue(c, null));

return (int)result.Max();
```

Comment: Granted, this does not actually solve the original problem. But gets the job done. Would be interesting to get the solution to the original problem though.